# have_content in JS message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I need to check text message inside toastr-rails. But in my tests, text isn't show. How to run rspec with js? Or I should do something else?

```
scenario "#email" do
  fill_in "user_email", with: "johndoe@mail.com"
  click_on "Save"
  expect(page).to have_content 'Your account has been updated successfully'
end
```

My message template(toastr)

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% flash.each do |f| %>
    <% type = f[0].to_s.gsub('alert', 'error').gsub('notice', 'info') %>
    toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= f[1] %>');
    <% end %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how it worked

1. Use the `Capybara.javascript_driver` in your scenario:

```html
scenario "#email", :js => true do
  fill_in "user_email", with: "johndoe@mail.com"
  click_on "Save"
  expect(page).to have_content 'Your account has been updated successfully'
end
```

2. Check for message inside the `div` that toastr generates

`within(".toast-info") do
  expect(page).to have_text('Your account has been updated successfully')
end`